# How to pass function from class parent component to child functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I have been trying is this:

The parent component is a class component with a function logToConsole. I summarized the code below:

I am trying to pass Function from parent component to a child functional component

**Parent Component**:

```
logToConsole = () => {
  console.log("test);
}
render(){
  return(
    <ChildComp logThis={this.logToConsole} />
  )
}
```

**The ChildComp is**:

```
const ChildComp = (props) => (
  <button onClick={()=>props.logThis()}>Click Here</button>
)

export default ChildComp
```

However I am getting `logThis` is not a function. How do I solve this issue is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: No I am getting an error

Comment: Do you have configuration for class properties in place?

Comment: @sambit Just tried that on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-npmho5) and got no error. The only issue I see in the code you posted is that you're missing a closing '"'":  `console.log("test");`

Comment: It is working as expected [CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-gagarin-u8fv8?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 2):

Parent:

```
import React from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends React.Component {
  logToConsole = () => {
    console.log("test");
  };
  render() {
    return <Child log={this.logToConsole} />;
  }
}
export default Parent;
```

Child:

```
export default function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <button onClick={props.log}>Log</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Live Demo**

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Not Working in the sandbox or as is

Comment: Sry Thanks its working

Answer (score 0):

Your child component should be:

```
<button onClick={props.logThis}>Click Here</button>
```

Comment: I tried it without the brackets however in that case the function doesnt work

Comment: @sambit My answer is the exact same as Abdulmuhaymin's answer down below.

Answer (score 0):

```
logToConsole = () => {
  console.log("test);
}
```

should become

```
const logToConsole = () => {
    console.log("test");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. What I think is missing is that you need to return the render in the ChildComp

```
const ChildComp = (props) => (
  return <button onClick={()=>props.logThis()}>Click Here</button>
)

export default ChildComp
```

I also think you need to setup configurations for class properties if you don't intend to use constuctor function.

Assuming you use constructor function in your class you should be fine all you need to do is this

```
constructor() {
  this.logToConsole = this.logToConsole.bind(this)
}
```

However if you are using a class properties use the instructions provided here
https://btholt.github.io/complete-intro-to-react-v6/class-properties

Comment: No Its showing target element not found in the console something is wrong

Comment: You need to return  button in the child component